# Running a text in an Excel cell as a formula in a different cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I want to run a text in an Excel cell as a formula in a different cell. 
For example,
I write a text in `Sheets("FON") range("j5)"` as `VLOOKUP(Subeler!A2;FON!A:F;6;0)`
and 
i want to run this text as formula in the `sheets("Subeler")` in `range ("h2")`
how can i do this please help me?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not directly using this formula in the cell you need it in?

Comment: I think you need the INDIRECT function

Comment: INDIRECT function not working

Comment: Then show us this "not working" `INDIRECT`-function. You may have entered it incorrectly. Otherwise we are not able to help you, as `INDIRECT` should be the way to go. Your text-function is missing a closing bracket. Don't know if this might be your problem.

Comment: oh well, forget about the part with the missing bracket.